# Jenkins: get build details by artifact's md5

Tags: jenkins, md5, fingerprinting

In Jenkins I am "fingerprinting" all build artifacts from several jobs. Now i have md5 from one of artifacts, but can't have the artifact itself.

Can I get the build details (which job, which build# is the artifact from) by md5, without having the artifact? On the UI they have only "upload file" box and "check" button.

UP: Reading the [docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fingerprint) thoroughly shows that you can view `JENKINS_HOME/fingerprints` directory.

So the question is - how to do it if you don't have the access to files on jenkins' host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can access the fingerprint data by using the URL:

```
http://<host:port>/fingerprint/<md5sum>/api/xml
```

Comment: btw, if you don't tail url with /api/xml you can get the links to appropriate builds right away.